# MS-Access: How to create form where user can add results (tblResults) to a tests (tblTests)?

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, data-entry

I am creating a database that contains Product information (tblProductInfo), a list of test methods (tblTests), and the results that the product gets (tblResults).

I'm adding forms so that a user can enter the results of a previous or new product. This information will be added once all the testing for that product is done. So, I would like to be able to show a list of the tests from tblTests, and have the user enter the results in a text box of some sort displayed directly next to the tests. I can't figure out a way to do so, where it will then save all the results that the user entered.

I have created a form with a subform, where the subform shows the 2 columns (tests and results) and when I change it to allow DataEntry, it gets rid of all the test names. I need it to keep the test names displayed, but allow entry in the results column.

Any ideas?
Below is a screenshot of an example of what I would like, although I need the Results column to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Create a continuous subform with only the tblresults as the recordsource, and for the header or each field of results use the related test as the label is how I would do it.  Set allow additions to yes, allow edits to no allow deletions to no.